# customer login link should be change to logout/sign out but still it is showing login

Tags: magento2, cache, customer-account

After customer login link should be change to logout / sign out but still it is showing login.

For that I have add `cacheable=false` from layout file when calling custom block. Also flush cache pragmatically during get customer session.

Please advice how to flush cache without command.

Comment: Any solution on this #arjun @arjun